# Tumblr: Search returning no search results

Tags: forms, search, tumblr

I'm new to tumblr and am trying to implement Search in a custom theme.  I have:

```
<form action="/search" method="get" id="search-form">
    <input type="text" name="q" class="query" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit" />
    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

I have about a dozen posts.  Whenever I search for anything in any post, Tumblr always returns no search results.  I feel like I'm missing something.  Am I to implement or set any configuration anywhere else in the theme?  What else is needed to implement search in a user's Tumblr theme?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I noticed I get no search results even if I search my blog from the admin page (http://www.tumblr.com/blog/[blogname]). I wonder if Tumblr's search feature is currently broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I use. Put this into the `<head>` of your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function handleThis(formElm)
{
window.location="/tagged/"+formElm.number.value+"";
return false;
}
-->
</script>
```

And place this where you want the search box to appear:

```
<form onsubmit="return handleThis(this)">
<div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="{lang:Search}" name="Submit"/></div>
<div class="input"><input onfocus="this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Search. Then hit enter.';" type="text" value="{lang:Search}. Then hit enter." name="number"/></div>
</form>
```

Use CSS to style as you wish. This will search your tags only, but unlike the regular Tumblr search it works.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting no results when my blog was password protected. I removed the password protection from Tumblr Dashboard > settings > blog name > password and it started returning results again.